# Issue when appending special characters string its replacing with Unicode format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-entities

When I try to append a string in some input type text value field in php
using JavaScript then it replaces special character in Unicode format
like `` ` `` (a backtick) with &#39.

How to display as special character in input type text value?

I try to convert from this function but after appending its display in Unicode format
in php htmlentities() function use for display special character in input field
but I have no idea in java script or jQuery.

```
<input type ="text" id="LBitemName">   //php text field

 function htmlEntities(str) {
    for (var result = '', index = 0, charCode; !isNaN(charCode = str.charCodeAt(index++));) {
                            result += '\\u' + ('0000' + charCode.toString(16)).slice(-4);
    }
  return result;
}



var output = htmlEntities(response[0]['Name']);  //get value from ajax

$('#LBitemName').html(output);  //append in text field
```

Please guide me for this issue

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's not clear what your desired outcome is. Do you want to rewrite the htmlspecialchars function in JavaScript?

Comment: yes i return htmlEntities() output than append in text field value but its display ' etc symbol in unicode value like  &#39

Comment: @mr lister i update my question  and add full code